# React Native: Keydown global event listener

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have an external RFID reader connected to the Android app. There's a touch gesture when I tap on an external reader device to my react native app. Also, It manages to write down the output data but only in input text fields.

My problem is, the event seems like a `keydown` but I can't add a `window.addEventListener` to react native `window` or `document` does not recognized. Is there any alternative listener that I can use to get the output from external reader?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const rfid = window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
    return () => window.removeEventListener(rfid)
  }, [])
```

Comment: I hit this a few years back, and ended up creating a full-screen `<View/>` on top of the app and using that to catch events. Failing that this library looks useful (haven't used it) https://github.com/kevinejohn/react-native-keyevent

Comment: @BenClayton The library didn't work. I guess I just have to use different module  with full screen view as well specifically for capturing RFID output only. Thanks for the idea